# Last Update time in widget

Tags: widgets, updates

I have a widget which can be updated every time with few values and admin update it on daily basis now how to get its last update time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save the widget, you can save a field (which won't be setable in the admin interface) which stores the current time and then use that when you go to do the widget output.

Comment: I have added manual query on last updated time of table and fix this issue ...

`$recentposts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(UPDATE_TIME,'-06:00','+5:00'),'%b %d, %Y %l:%i %p') as UPDATETIMEWidget FROM   information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'wp_options'");
echo $recentposts[0]->UPDATETIMEWidget;`